# InvalidCastException error with clearing value of date picker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, null, datepicker, .net

I use code such as this to clear out the values in several text boxes:

```
Private Sub RibbonButtonInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RibbonButtonInsert.Click

    UpdateDataSource()

    StudentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(True)
    DatePickerDateOfBirth.Value = ""
    RichEditBoxForeName.Focus()
    StudentsBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub
```

Because the date picker control did not clear out like the other controls did, I tried:

```
    DatePickerDateOfBirth.Value = ""
```

but it does not clear out. Instead, I get an "InvalidCastException".

Can you show me what coding I need to properly clear out the value in this data picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not clearing it out, you are assigning a string value to it. and as it is a Date type, the assignment is wrong.

the assigned value must be a Date format, you can do this:

```
DatePickerDateOfBirth.Value = Date.MinValue
```

later you can check and if the value is equal to MinValue, then the date is not set.

Answer (score 1):

You cant set DateTimePicker Value to null or empty string it's value must be a date

but you can but a checkbox in datetimepicker using [ShowCheckBox Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showcheckbox.aspx)

and then use dateTimePicker.Checked = false [dateTimePicker.Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.checked%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)